Linearization of concentration dependent diffusion
I am interested in linearizing parabolic equations of the form
$$v_{t}(x,y)=\nabla \cdot((1-F(v))\nabla v) $$
Where $F(v)$ is nonlinear in general, around a stationary state $v_{\star}(x,y)=c$ for which $F(v_{\star})=0$. I first tried tackling the problem in one dimension, where we'd have:
$$v_t=v_{xx}-F(v)v_{xx}-F_{x}(v)v_{x}$$
Introducing a small perturbation of the form $\mu=v-v_{\star}$ we could make a Taylor expansion around $v_\star$, however I don't understand how the linearization of the last term would be, and don't think I know how to linearize derivatives so what I've got so far based on gut feel is
$$\mu_{t}=\mu_{xx}-(\frac{\partial F}{\partial v})\Big|_{v_{\star}}\mu_{xx}+...$$
I would very much appreciate is someone could guide me through the derivation step by step. Does the linearization's form vary case by case depending on $F(v)$?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The linearization of the (nonlinear) equation of order $m$
$$
F(x,\partial^{\beta}v)=0; \qquad 0\le |\beta|\le m
$$
around a solution $v=v_*$ is the equation
$$
\left(\sum_{0\le|\alpha|\le m}a_{\alpha}\partial^\alpha\right)\mu=0
$$
in the sense that $v_*+\mu$ satisfies the original equation up to linear terms.
Here,
$$
a_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial(\partial^{\alpha}v)}(x,\partial^{\beta}v_*)
$$
In your one-dimensional case, your equation is
$$
v_t-v_{xx}+F(v)v_{xx}+F'(v)(v_x)^2=0
$$
(it is not clear what you mean by $F_x(v)$)
and, therefore (my first index in the multi index is for $t$-derivatives, the second index is for $x$-derivatives)
$$
a_{0,0}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(x,c,0,0)=F'(c)v_{*xx}+F''(c)(v_{*x})^2=0;
$$
$$
a_{1,0}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v_t}(x,c,0,0)=1;
$$
$$
a_{0,1}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v_x}(x,c,0,0)=2F'(c)v_{*x}=0;
$$
$$
a_{1,1}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v_{xt}}(x,c,0,0)=0
$$
and, finally,
$$
a_{2,0}=0; \quad a_{0,2}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v_{xx}}(x,c,0,0)=-1+F(c)=-1
$$
Your linearized equation is just the linear heat equation
$$
\mu_t=\mu_{xx}.
$$

Thank you for your reply! The index in $F_{x}(v)$ is meant to be for the derivative of $F(v(x))$ with respect to x. I feared that the linearization would kill off the interesting bits of the equation, but perhaps I could try something for higher orders.

When I did the spectral analysis of the pde it gave a dispersion relation of $i\omega T(u)=k^{2}(T(F)T(u)-T(u))$ where $T$ is shorthand for applying the fourier transforms for $x$ and $t$. Since the heat equation had a relation of the form $i\omega T(u)=-k^{2} T(u)$ I thought the nonlinear terms would make it more interesting, but since $T(F)T(u)$ is at the very least second order perhaps I need to taylor expand further.  Could you share the general formula for the second order approximation in the notation you used?
